# jQuery: using $(this) inside of $.ajax success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, this

I'm making an $.ajax call, and the following code does not work as intended. The alert results in 'undefined'

```
$(document).ready( function {
  $(".elem").on("click", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax( {
      url: 'index.php',
      data: {
        'action': 'something'
      },
      success: function() {
        alert($(this).data("foobar"));
      }
    });
  });
)};
```

However, I was able to get it working by adding an alias to `$(this)` before entering the ajax function.

```
$(document).ready( function {
  $(".elem").on("click", function(e) {

    var old_this = $(this);

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax( {
      url: 'index.php',
      data: {
        'action': 'something'
      },
      success: function() {
        alert(old_this.data("foobar"));
      }
    });
  });
)};
```

I can't assign unique IDs to the element being clicked, so accessing it via $("#id") isn't an option.

Is there a more standardized approach to accessing the $(this) that existed before entering the success function or does this way work just fine?

Comment: maybe by using `context:this` for the object passed in `.ajax()`?

Comment: You are doing exactly what you should be doing. My only recommendation would be to prefix the variable name with a $. This has become a somewhat common practice for variables that reference a jQuery object. Ex. $old_this You should name your variable a little better though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way that you have it is just fine.  By default `this` in jQuery ajax callbacks is the ajax settings object (you can set via `$.ajaxSettings`).  [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) also has a `context` property that you can set:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: data,
    context: this,
    success: success
});
```

Then you could use `$(this)` as expected, but personally I find the reassignment of `this` easier to understand.  You may want to pick a better variable name than `old_this`, though.

Comment: Ah, the context property is not one I knew about. That's what I was wondering, whether or not the reference to $(this) was passed in some other way besides setting a variable like I did. Thanks so much!

Comment: `this` is a reference to the DOM element of invocation, so it is actually the `ajax` object.

Comment: Caution: Now the new_this is old_this... so you do not have new_this anymore. Just saying!  That why assigning to a var sound better because you have reference to both old and new this.